# Margin после row Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Ребят, не получается сделать `margin-top` для `.row` класса, т.е. `margin` для второго `.row` идет не от предыдущего `.row`, а от самого верха страницы.

Структура:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: приведенный код не имеет проблем с отступами. Приведите фрагмент кода, где ошибка продемонстрирована.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что не "от самого верха страницы" а от предыдущего блока.

**Эффект схлопывания.**

> При рассмотрении блочной модели была затронута тема схлопывания
>   отступов. Этот эффект наблюдается, когда у блочных элементов
>   расположенных рядом друг с другом по вертикали, отступы не
>   суммируются, а объединяются между собой. Само схлопывание действует на
>   два и более блока (один может быть вложен внутрь другого) с отступами
>   сверху или снизу, при этом примыкающие отступы комбинируются в один.
>   Этот эффект работает только для блоков, у которых не заданы поля и
>   границы. Для отступов слева и справа схлопывание никогда не
>   применяется.

Пример:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, assumenda?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis deserunt temporibus aspernatur.
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Решение: Применять один margin (`margin-top;` или `margin-bottom;`) . Или заменить на `padding`.

Comment: Проблема была в версии boostrap 3.3.7. Попробуйте этот код на этой версии.

Comment: @rammtw, поменяла на 3.3.7 - одинаково

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего, вы имеете дело со "схлопыванием отступов". Почитайте эту статью, в ней указано, из-за чего возникает и как справить.

https://habrahabr.ru/post/257327/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.